# getEventListerners() return empty object while inspecting detached DOM tree

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-devtools

I have some detached DOM in my application. Used Chrome Dev tools to find the function which holds the element.

getEventListeners(element) function in chrome developer tools returns `Object {}`.

That means No events have been attached to the element?

Comment: ALl are right. Please share what you tried.

Comment: Without seeing more code, it seems that yes, there are no event handlers attached to your element. I've tried doing what you did in chrome, detaching an element I knew had event listeners, and `getEventListeners` worked for me once the object was detached.

Comment: `getEventListeners` will return empty `Object {}` if no event handlers attached. Thanks!